# Не добавляется JTable в JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Возникла проблема при добавлении таблицы с данными по нажатии на кнопку. Собственно, сам код:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{

private static final int h = 300;
private static final int w = 615;

private JPanel rootPanel;
private JButton addButton;
private JButton updateButton;
private JButton deleteButton;
private JButton selectButton;
private JPanel innerPanel;
private JComboBox selectCombo;
private JComboBox deleteCombo;
private JComboBox updateCombo;
private JComboBox addCombo;
private JPanel mypanel;
private JScrollPane scroll;

public Gui() {
    super("DB Manager");
    //selectProduct = new SelectProduct();
    //scroll = new JScrollPane(selectProduct.getTable());
    setContentPane(rootPanel);
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(w, h);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    //...//

    selectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            switch (selectCombo.getSelectedIndex()) {
                //..//
                case 3:
                    SelectProduct selectProduct = new SelectProduct();
                    scroll = new JScrollPane(selectProduct.getTable());
                    mypanel = new JPanel();
                    JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton();
                    mypanel.add(b);
                    mypanel.add(scroll);
                    break;
                //..//
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**class SelectProduct**

```
//..//

public class SelectProduct {

private DBWorker worker;

private JTable table;

private String[] columnNames;
private String[][] data;

private static final String query = "select * from product";

public SelectProduct() {
    worker = new DBWorker();

    data = new String[20][20];
    columnNames = new String[] {
            "Название продукта",
            "Название поставщика",
            "Цена",
            "Вес"
    };
    execute();
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
}

private void execute() {
    int i = 0;

    try {
        Statement statement = worker.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            data[i][0] = resultSet.getString("name");
            data[i][1] = resultSet.getString("supplier_name");
            data[i][2] = resultSet.getString("price");
            data[i][3] = resultSet.getString("weight");

            i++;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public JTable getTable() {
    return table;
    }

}
```

В итоге, при нажатии на "Вывести" и выборе нужного пункта таблица не добавляется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `scroll = new JScrollPane(selectProduct.getTable());` надо наверное потом на какую-то панель добавить (внутри `actionPerformed`).

Comment: Вы свой `scroll` на фрейм добавляете?

Comment: Добавил `mypanel` и в нее добавляю `scroll`, но опять не добавляется. Даже обычный `JRadioButton`.

Comment: Шел 2016 год, люди до сих пор писали GUI руками. Поставьте уже какой-нибудь плагин (Eclipse WindowBuilder, например), не мучайтесь и не тратьте на это время.

Comment: Уже поздно, хочу это полностью закончить :)

Comment: ну вот в mypanel и добавляйте, предварительно удалив оттуда старое. Вообще без необходимости лучше не пересоздавать jTable, а действовать через TableModel (создав свою реализацию, или через DefaultTableModel)

Comment: Не помогает. В `case` оставил только это: `JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton(); mypanel.add(b);` И в конструктор добавил: `mypanel = new JPanel();`

Comment: mypanel заново создавать не надо при добавлении таблицы. У вас есть ваши списки и кнопки сверху, и mypanel под ними. Считайте, что mypanel - это гнездо, в которое надо воткнуть вашу таблицу. Из него надо вынуть предыдущую таблицу (`mypanel.removeAll` вынесет все дочерние компоненты), и вставить новую (`mypanel.add(new JScrollPane(table)`). Если не поможет, покажите код `initComponents` (без слушателей и заполнения списков данными), а то уже два дня гадаем, что у вас там куда вложено и как размечено.

Comment: "mypanel заново создавать не надо при добавлении таблицы" - это не очень понял. Т.е. `mypanel = new JPanel();` не нужно в конструктордобавлять? Если это не добавить, то у меня `NPE` выскакивает. В `initComponents` у меня просто на каждую кнопку повешен обработчик и все. Смотря какой пункт выбран, открывается нужное окно.

Comment: в конструктор добавьте, она должен создаваться **один** раз за время жизни вашей формы. Внутри свича ее пересоздавать не надо

Comment: Я так и делал. Все равно в эту `mypanel` ничего не добавляется. Может `mypanel` из формы удалить и создать в коде только?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, сам нашел решение:

На форме для нужного элемента нужно активировать чекбокс "Custom create". А затем уже в методе `createUIComponents` создавать самому нужные элементы.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали `mypanel = new JPanel();` но никуда её не добавили. Вам нужно её добавить видимо в `rootPanel`, т.е.:

```
 selectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            switch (selectCombo.getSelectedIndex()) {
                //..//
                case 3:
                    //..//
                    rootPanel.add(mypanel);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Верно, но для этого нужно добавить такую строчку `rootPanel = new JPanel();`, иначе будет `NPE`. Но если добавить эту строчк, то это уже будет "другая" `rootPanel`.

Comment: @compl я не уверен что и как у вас, потому что у вас на картинке 8 элементов, а в код нигде они не создаются. Смысл что вам надо взять ту панель на которую добавляются все эти элементы и на неё добавить таблицу.

Comment: Я эти элементы через `form` нарисовал (добавил скрин в вопрос).